# Laravel - how much time passed since cache

Tags: caching, laravel, laravel-4

Lets say I use remember function to store the data in cache.

And when user is in the site, I want him to be able to know how old the data is which he see. And so he will have option to get fresh data if he does not like old.

One thing - I could try to check the cached file date, but I am not sure how the folder structure and file names are made. Could try to understand by checking how cache works, but maybe there is something done with this? I did not find.

Comment: I am looking for a solution for this as well, I'm thinking I'll add timestamps to the cache table on the database.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Get the full path for the given cache key.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return string
 */
protected function path($key)
{
    $parts = array_slice(str_split($hash = md5($key), 2), 0, 2);

    //return $this->directory.'/'.join('/', $parts).'/'.$hash;
    return Config::get('cache.path') .'/'.join('/', $parts).'/'.$hash;
}


public function getTest() {

    $users = DB::table('shops')->remember(1, 'key')->get();

    echo 'Now: ' . date('H:i:s') . '<br>';
    echo 'Cache saved at: ' . date('H:i:s', filemtime($this->path('key'))) . '<br>';

}
```

THe path() function is copied and edited from FileStore.php file. I better way would be to extend this but I am not sure how. So would be good if someone tell.

Comment: Thanks! Laravel 5.5 is using sha1() instead md5()

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 5:

```
$parts = array_slice(str_split($hash = sha1($cacheKey), 2), 0, 2);
$path = storage_path('framework/cache/data').'/'.implode('/', $parts).'/'.$hash;
```